# Where to find the logs of the services started by systemd at computer boot?

Tags: debian, systemd

I am running a Debian unstable with `systemd`, at boot I have a few services which are marked as `FAILED` (and not `OK`), but the log is too fast for me to grab the name of the failed service.

I wonder if there is a way to get this boot log once the system is up and running (I am NOT speaking about the kernel log which are reachable with `dmesg` but the `services`). And, the `service --status-all` does not really help because it only list the services that are on/off but not the one that have failed at boot.

So, any hint is welcome !

Comment: Try `journalctl`, then searching for the names of the failed services. There are also options to that command to filter on service name from the start.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

```
 systemctl --state=failed
```

[`man systemctl`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--state=) says:

> --state=
>
> The argument should be a comma-separated list of unit LOAD, SUB, or ACTIVE states. When listing units, show only those in specified states. Use --state=failed to show only failed units.

Run (as `root`):

```
systemctl status <service-name>
```

> status [PATTERN...|PID...]]
>
> Show terse runtime status information about one or more units, followed by most recent log data from the journal.

Also:

```
journalctl -u <service-name> -b
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what start says itself, but all of this is most of the times empty, so what else?